# A name for hat collectors?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy, winterfest

The [Stack Exchange Winter Bash 2013](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/?cb=1) has me thinking about hats, as my collection is growing. I know that the terms for people who collect specific things are generally obscure, but they do exist. Perhaps the most common of those types of words is "philatelist"— a person who collects stamps.

Is there a similar word for a person who collects hats?

Comment: Although I don't know a similar word for a person who collects hats, I know a couple more words related (more or less) to stamp collecting: *[timbromaniac](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/timbromaniac)* “(philately) a person who is passionate about stamp-collecting” and *[philometrist](http://www.talktalk.co.uk/reference/dictionaries/difficultwords/data/d0009938.html)*,  “collector of envelopes, etc., for their postal meter impressions”

Comment: "Stack Exchange user (December 2013 - January 2014)"

Comment: Nice hat, btw. :-)

Comment: Perhaps in decades to come, when ***millinophilia*** (excessive love of hat-wearing) is eventually recognised as a serious disease, historians and [epidemiologists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemiology) will blame Stack Exchange for starting the epidemic. I'm already infected (I've just put on my "Chuck Yeagar" hat, even though I know nothing about him, and I've no idea how I got this "secret" hat! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think the "Chuck Yeagar" is for answering a question quickly, but I don't know what the time range is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't *really* a specific word for someone who likes/collects hats (i.e. - you won't find one in a dictionary). But people who are interested in hats may well know that...

> [*A hat maker is called a **milliner.***](http://uk.ask.com/question/what-do-you-call-a-hat-maker)

...in which case they would doubtless understand this coinage that I found in Google Books...

> [*Sadly, living in sunny, funny LA, l have to wait for bad weather to visit the milliner. lf you're a **millinophile** like me, don't miss The Millionairess.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=millinophile%20%22dont%20miss%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Since wealthy people could more easily afford to buy lots of expensive hats, it's at least *possible* that "The Millionairess" is a deliberate play on words there, but probably it's just a coincidence.

Comment: Perhaps this is "correct", but looking at that word I can't help but think it describes a person who has some wierd fetish for hat makers.

Comment: You could call the young ones millinials; to the confusion of all.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Per the first sentence of my answer, I make no claim for it being "correct". But obviously it was a "plausible" coinage by Meredith Alexander (the cited author). Firstly because we must assume she expected her readers to understand it - but secondly (and more importantly *to me*), there's the fact that it occurred to me *independently*. I only searched for it on Google Books because I guessed someone else would have thought along the same lines. Anyway, we can't allow paedophiles to give a bad name to *all* lovers - I'm all for *Anglophiles*, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think this is as close as I'm going to get with this one. +1, and the big green!

Answer (score 8):

**capel** is the Latin word for *hat, headdress*.

For a neologism, **capellophile** is a possibility, and seems to be in limited use in French slang already.

Comment: +1. I like the sound of this one. Rolls off the tongue quite nicely.

Comment: [A hat fetish eh? A capellophile?](http://www.graffe.com/forums/showthread.php?72866-Gay-By-Choice/page3)

Comment: @Susan: I'm ashamed to admit I didn't actually know *L. capel = hat*, so without context I'd have probably guessed *capellophile = lover of chapels* (or maybe *lover of unaccompanied vocal music* :). But the key point is we both came up with credible neologisms, and it turns out Google finds exactly one instance of each. Yours, of course, has the more august pedigree. But at least my "recorded instance in the wild" was in a *published book*, whereas I only found yours in an online chat forum.

Comment: Enough already! Although I gave you a supporting reference *from an Anglophone*, I didn't actually upvote because I wouldn't have been able to guess the meaning without context (on account of relative illiteracy, obviously! :) But given the French are supposed to be world leaders in the fashion industry and matters sartorial, I suppose I must upvote and be damned.

Comment: Mixing Latin and Greek roots makes me sad. How about using πέτασος, which is a [particular type of hat](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pe%2Ftasos&la=greek&can=pe%2Ftasos0) (a broad-brimmed felt one - I couldn't find a Greek word for "hat" in general) to neologize **petasophile**?

Answer (score 1):

I applaud Susan and FumbleFingers for their contributions. My own preference is to keep it simple if slightly vulgar, and denote those with an enthusiasm for hats as 'hat fetishist'.